# How are Ivy build projects in Jenkins supposed to be set up?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, jenkins, ivy

I'm running the following versions:

- Jenkins v1.440
- Jenkins Ivy Plugin v1.20

The branch in SVN I'm currently trying to build looks like this:

- branch

  - product

    - module1

      - module1.build (ant build file)
      - ivy.xml (module1 ivy descriptor file)
    - module2

      - module2.build (ant build file)
      - ivy.xml (module2ivy descriptor file)
    - module3

      - module3.build (ant build file)
      - ivy.xml (module3ivy descriptor file)

Currenly I've set up separate Ivy projects in Jenkins to check out each module in SVN, and then run the ant build file directly. This works fine (although I see no module dependencies).

From the plugin doc it looks like I should be setting up one Ivy project in Jenkins, and be getting from "branch\product\" in SVN, instead of "branch\product\module1", "branch\product\module2"?

If that is the case, how do I point this one Ivy project to each build file for each component? Am I supposed to use one build file for all components?

How would this work with multiple SVN locations? Would Ivy be able to find module dependencies in other SVN locations? What if I have multiple branches of the same component? Does Ivy simply search for binary dependencies in ALL Ivy descriptor files in a particular path?

Please let me know if you need any other info to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've currently set it up is a valid way to do it (although you should be seeing job dependencies if your modules do actually depend on each other).  Setting it up as one multi-module Ivy Project is another valid option, the benefit being that you only have to manage one job configuration per set of related modules.

There are two ways to do a multi-module Ivy Build.

1. Create a branch-level build file that intelligently delegates to all the Ivy modules.
2. Standardize your Ant build file names (to build.xml for example) in each module and get the Jenkins Ivy Plugin to run each module build as a separate job.

For an example of how to do #1, see:

- Ivy Docs - http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiproject.html
- Examples in the Jenkins Ivy Project - https://github.com/jenkinsci/ivy-plugin/tree/master/src/test/resources/example-project

To do #2 you can expand the Advanced section in the Ivy Module Configuration section of your Ivy Project job configuration and check the "Build modules as separate jobs" option.  Your Ant build file names need to be the same in each module, and ideally the targets to call and location of ivy.xml files are identical as well (although those last two can be overridden per-module if you need to).  From then on, all the paths in the job config must be relative to each module directory (Ex. artifacts to archive would just be "target/**" or whatever and that would be applied to each module after it builds).

To handle multiple branches of the same set of Ivy modules you need to have a separate Ivy Project for each branch and specify unique values for the "Ivy branch" field in the Ivy Project configuration.